# First Character is not displaying in input field useForms

Tags: reactjs, input, redux, react-hooks, react-hook-form

When I click on Submit, it gives an error "required". But when i type text it doesn't take first character. On entering first character it only removes "required" message.
Can you please tell me why it is not showing first character.

```
<div className="input-field">
    <label htmlFor="state">State</label>
       <input
       placeholder="State"
       name="state"
       autoComplete="off"
       type="text" 
       value={state}
       onChange = { e => setState(e.target.value)}
       ref={register({required:'required'})}  
       />
       <span className="error">{errors.state && errors.state.message}</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably related to the usage of `react-hook-form` with your custom controlled logic (`value` and `onChange`).

If you don't need the input to be controlled, I would recommend dropping the `value` and `onChange` props from the input, as they seem to be conflicting with the package.

Comment: we have a FAQ here as well: https://react-hook-form.com/faqs#Whyisfirstkeystrokeisnotworking

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, because `setState` is an asynchronous method. Try to add the `async` on your `onChange` function and `await this.setState()`. It should capture all the input characters.